# how to insert multiple rows not at the same time in one column in php

Tags: mysql

i need your help for my graduation project
the system is for students and the admin
if the admin wants to send a violation to a specific student he will choose the id of student (records in the students table in phpmyadmin)
then he write the violation.
when the admin click the submit button how i write that i need to record the violation under the student id that i choose?
and how to record another violation under the same student (not at the same time) without cancel the first one?
the idea that i think about is insert multiple row under one column but i dont know how to do it.

this is the violation page

```
<h1 style="color:green;">  New Violation  </h1> 

<form action ="includes/addviolation.inc.php" method="POST", enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" name="size" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<?php 


$sql = "SELECT student_id FROM students";
     $records = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


echo "<select name= 'student_id'>";
echo '<option value="">'.'--- Please Select student ---'.'</option>';

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($records))
{
    echo "<option value='". $row['student_id']."'>".$row['student_id'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
<p style="color:green; font-size:15px;">violation: </p>
<textarea id="violation" class="text" cols="80" rows ="5" name="violation" required></textarea>

<br><input type="submit" name ="vupload" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a `student_violation` table with `id (int), student_id (integer), violation (text) and timestamp (datetime)` columns, and insert each violation in a row with the `student_id` and `timestamp`, and now you will have `one_to_many` relationship between students and violations.

Comment: but i want to bring the student id from table named students